# Bind click on TextInputEditText in TextInputLayout

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I've created a custom control whose layout is roughly like this

```
<TextInputLayout>
   <TextInputEditText></TextInputEditText>
</TextInputLayout>
```

For a use case, I would like to attach a command to the click event on the TextInputLayout in order to open up a datepicker fragment from the view model. So I proceeded like this:

```
<MyCustomView
... 
app:MvxBind="Click SaveDateCommand"/>
```

However, the click event wont trigger the "SaveDateCommand". In my control I have added stylable properties to control the "focusable" and "focusableInTouchMode" of the TextInputEditText widget; I've set those to false to no avail. I also went the custom binding route. Didn't work either. As of know I have written the barebones layout for my control into the main layout to bind a click with a command in TextInputEditText.

```
<TextInputLayout>
<TextInputEditText
app:MvxBind="Click SaveDateCommand"/>
</TextInputLayout>
```

However, I have the gut feeling that there has a to be a better way to do it. Thank you for your share of expertise on this one.

Comment: did you `android:clickable="true"` on the LinearLayout ?

Comment: If nothing else is working, you can simply add a transparent button over your edit text and bind to that click event.